# How do I dump data for a given date

Tags: mongodb

I am using mongoexport for exporting data for a given dates..my command is this

```
mongoexport -d project -c coll  --csv -o result -f source -q '{"date":{"$gte":"new Date(2011,1,25)","lt":"new Date(2011,2,26)"}}'
```

but it is not exporting result...i have data stored for 25-feb-2011 and 26-feb-2011 in database..how do I query for dates?

Comment: Shouldn't it read "$lt"?

Comment: Is export work without query? If so, i suppose instead of 'lt' you should use '$lte' and all will be okay

Comment: Yes export is working without query..and i am using $lt only...i types "lt" wrongly here..what can be the reason..why its not working

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem.. I fixed it by using the epoch time..

You can check here 
http://www.epochconverter.com/

I was using java .. so i used

Date x = new Date (year, month, day)

and got the epoch using x.getTime() and sent it to mongoexport

so ur mongo export statement would be

mongoexport -d project -c coll  --csv -o result -f source -q '{"date":{$gte:(Date(1295913600)),$lt:(Date(1298678400)}}'

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the way you are specifying the dates.

Firstly, I don't think `new Date(....)` should be in quotes (would be treated as a string literal not a date?).

Secondly, it looks like new `Date(Y,M,D)` cannot be used here to specify a date - that gives me the following error:

> Assertion: 10340:Failure parsing JSON string near...

I think instead you need to speciy the date numerically.

e.g. 

`new Date(1234567890)`

So the whole thing would be something like:

```
mongoexport -d project -c coll  --csv -o result -f source -q '{"date":{"$gte":new Date(x)","$lt":new Date(y)}}'
```

where x = the numerical representation of your start date and y = the end date.
Also, added the missing "$" for the "lt" as already pointed out.

**Update:**
Re: how to find the numerical representation. Had to play around a bit in the mongo shell as relatively new to this myself.
here's an example of what I did the mongo shell to get the number (e.g. for 25-feb:

```
> new Date(2009,1,25) * 1
```

which gives:

> 1235520000000

In the shell again, if you then do:

```
> new Date(1235520000000)
```

It will confirm it is the correct date:

```
ISODate("2009-02-25T00:00:00Z")
```

Comment: Well how do I get numerical representation of date

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Wael's query above did not work for me with mongoexport version 2.2.4 but this one did:

```
$and:[{date:{$gte:new Date(1372801816000)}},{date:{$lt:new Date(1373061846000)}}]}
```

you'd have to replace the above two epoch numbers with your own. so the mongo export command looks something like (I used --jsonArray instead of --csv)

```
mongoexport -h your_host:port -d your_db -c your_collection --jsonArray -o output.js -q '{$and:[{date:{$gte:new Date(time_stamp_1)}},{date:{$lt:new Date(time_stamp_2)}}]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this and it seems the problem in the original post is that `new Date(2011,2,26)` shouldn't have been wrapped in quotes and `"lt"` should have been `"$lt"`.  Also, `new Date(2011,2,26)` is March 26, 2011 because javascript uses a 0-11 range for month values.