# Mongoexport: Issues using -q to specify date

Tags: mongodb, date, export

I'm having a problem using mongoexport with a query using dates. The question and answer here is almost exactly like my situation, but I can't figure out why it didn't work for me:
[How do I dump data for a given date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191186/how-do-i-dump-data-for-a-given-date)

Based on the answer there, I structured my query like this:

./mongoexport -d database  -c collection -f _id,zooniverse_user_id -q '{"created_at":{"$lt":new Date(1296540000)}}' --csv >users_before_feb_eleven.csv

I used this date/epoch time converter to convert ISODate("2011-02-01T00:00:00z") to 1296540000:

http://www.esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm

I don't get any errors, but it exports "0 records" (I should be getting around 10,000.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your epoch date value is not correct, using the mongo shell:

```
foo:PRIMARY> new Date(1296540000)
ISODate("1970-01-16T00:09:00Z")
```

You are basically using seconds, but its milliseconds, so you want to multiply by 1000 (or just add three zeroes) like this:

```
foo:PRIMARY> new Date(1296540000000)
ISODate("2011-02-01T06:00:00Z")
```

Comment: Awesome, that was easy. Thanks for the help!